# I want to sort list of dates like this 2022052200 with the format yyyymmddnumbers using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am having list like `[2022052300,2022052301,2022052201,2022052200,2022052101]`.

I want latest date and latest number.
Desired output must be,[2022052101,2022052200,2022052201,2022052300,2022052301]

Comment: What have you tried - where are you stuck?

Comment: Maybe I gave it away to quickly I'm not aware of the policy of stack regarding the answers

Answer (score 0):

Given your date format you can just use the sorted() method :

```py
a = [2022052300,2022052301,2022052201,2022052200,2022052101]
b = sorted(a)

latest_date = "{}/{}/{}".format(str(b[-1])[0:4], str(b[-1])[4:6], str(b[-1])[6:8])
latest_number = "{}".format(str(a[-1])[8:10])
print(latest_date, "\n", latest_number)
# 2022/05/23 - 01
```

Comment: Appreciate your efforts but output should be like this [2022052101,2022052200,2022052201,2022052300,2022052301] .Can we do this using RE?

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort it

```
l = [2022052300,2022052301,2022052201,2022052200,2022052101]
print(sorted(l))
```

result

```
[2022052101,2022052200,2022052201,2022052300,2022052301]
```

Comment: Not getting desired output.

Comment: @rrr You do for the example you've shown and any data like it.